# VS 2013. .NET4, same project, Namespace could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, using

Running VSPro 2013 on a x64 Win7 machine, creating a C# Console Application called PROJ, using .NET4 and using a class library I build IN THE SAME PROJECT.  Class lib is called CHILD1 in CHILD1NAMESPACE. In PROJ, I have `using CHILD1NAMESPACE;` and it works!

I then created CHILD2, in CHILD2NAMESPACE... IN THE SAME PROJECT... with the exact same settings as CHILD1 (.NET4 / Class Library).

`using CHILD2NAMESPACE;`  gives me an error!  *The Type or namespace CHILD2NAMESPACE could not be found...*

I've searched the web and most resolutions include switching frameworks because the class library and parent are using different frameworks. In my case, they are all using .NET4 (not client) and are within the same Project.  I've restarted VS several time... cleaned, re-built etc.

Any clues would be appreciated.

Thanks
-Ed

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you created **two projects** (csproj) inside **one solution**.
In order to make one project access the other one you must add a reference between the projects.

In orde to do that, right click over the the project that is not building and click on "Add reference" you can choose the solution and select the project being referenciated.

Comment: You are awesome. Yes. you were correct. I had to browse down into the /obj/Debug folder to find it but that was it. THANK YOU SO MUCH!